Learndash lms, how to override color review question over color solved question
I use Learndash LMS on my website and additionally use the "Quiz customizer for LearndDash" plugin. My problem is that when I click on the answer, I can no longer click the "Mark question" button and the color does not want to be overwritten (on right question list panel). How to edit the code so that the "Mark question" color overwrites the "Answered question" color (on right question list panel).
Purple is the "Mark Question" color and orange is the "Answered question" color
Ultimately, I want purple to overwrite orange after clicking the "Mark Question" button
Below is a screenshot from my website.
my website
I tried to find a place in the code where I could edit it, but unfortunately to no avail.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
